# How do I improve perfomance creating DataTable in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have following code and it's slow to load first time. CSV file is about 4mb 16000 rows.

```
        If Session("tb") Is Nothing Then
            Dim str As String()
            If (IsNothing(Cache("csvdata"))) Then
                str = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/test/feed.csv"))
                Cache.Insert("csvdata", str, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(12), TimeSpan.Zero)
            Else
                str = CType(Cache("csvdata"), Array)
            End If
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("Shape", GetType(System.String))
            dt.Columns.Add("Weight", GetType(System.Double))
            dt.Columns.Add("Color", GetType(System.String))
            dt.Columns.Add("Clarity", GetType(System.String))
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(System.Int32))
            dt.Columns.Add("CutGrade", GetType(System.String))

            For i As Integer = 1 To str.Length - 1
                Dim pattern As String = ",(?=([^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)"
                Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
                Dim t As String = rgx.Replace(str(i), "\")
                Dim s As String() = t.Split("\"c)
                Dim pr As Int32 = CType(s(5), Int32)
                Dim fpr As Int32
                Dim rate As Double
                Select Case pr
                    Case Is < 300
                        rate = 2
                    Case 301 To 600
                        rate = 1.7
                    Case Is > 600
                        rate = 1.16
                End Select
                fpr = Math.Round(pr * rate)
                Dim a As String() = {s(1), s(2), s(3), s(4), fpr, s(40)}
                dt.Rows.Add(a)
            Next

            Session("tb") = dt
            ListView1.DataSource = dt
            ListView1.DataBind()
        Else
            Dim x As DataTable = CType(Session("tb"), DataTable)
            ListView1.DataSource = x
            ListView1.DataBind()
        End If
```

csv file is cached and I assume this can share with everyone. 
(one person loads once in 12 hours)
Once I create Session, the page loads fast as well.
So, creating Datatable seems to be the slow process. 
This is first time to deal with datatable and I'm sure someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I have changed Cache to the original Datatable instead of CSV file.
It loads fast now, but I would like to know if this is a bad idea or not.

```
 Cache.Insert("csvdata", dt, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(12), TimeSpan.Zero)
```

Once it's stored in Cache, I can run Query against it using Linq.

**SAMPLE CSV** first 3 rows

```
Supplier ID,Shape,Weight,Color,Clarity,Price / Carat,Lot Number,Stock Number,Lab,Cert #,Certificate Image,2nd Image,Dimension,Depth %,Table %,Crown Angle,Crown %,Pavilion Angle,Pavilion %,Girdle Thinnest,Girdle Thickest,Girdle %,Culet Size,Culet Condition,Polish,Symmetry,Fluor Color,Fluor Intensity,Enhancements,Remarks,Availability,Is Active,FC-Main Body,FC- Intensity,FC- Overtone,Matched Pair,Separable,Matching Stock #,Pavilion,Syndication,Cut Grade,External Url
9349,Round,1.74,F,VVS1,13650.00,,IM-95-188-243,ABC,11228,,,7.81|7.85|4.62,59.00,62.00,34.00,13.00,,,Medium,,0,None,,Excellent,Very Good,Blue,Medium,,"",Not Specified,Y,,,,False,True,,,,Very Good,http://www.test/teste.
9949,Round,1.00,I,VVS1,6059.00,,IM-95-189-C021,ABC,212197,,,6.37|6.42|3.96,61.90,54.00,34.50,16.00,,,Thin,Slightly Thick,0,None,,Excellent,Good,,None,,"Additional pinpoints are not shown.",Guaranteed Available,Y,,,,False,True,,,,Very Good,http://www.test/test.
```

Comment: It takes about 7-8 seconds to load first time. My local test server is 10g ram Quad Xeon 1.86ghz

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128079.aspx) to read the CSV instead of splitting the strings yourself.

Also, if you use a List(Of CustomClass) where CustomClass has the Shape, Weight, Color, etc. properties you can avoid the unnecessary overhead of the DataTable and you can still do your LINQ queries against the List.

Pardon my C#, I do not have VB.NET installed on this box.

```
    public class Gemstone
    {
        public string Shape { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextFieldParser textFieldParser = new TextFieldParser("data.txt");
        textFieldParser.Delimiters = new string[] {","};
        textFieldParser.ReadLine(); // skip header line
        List<Gemstone> list = new List<Gemstone>(16000);  // allocate the list with your best calculated guess of its final size
        while(!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = textFieldParser.ReadFields();
            Gemstone gemstone = new Gemstone();
            gemstone.Shape = fields[1];
            gemstone.Weight = Double.Parse(fields[2]);
            gemstone.Color = fields[3];
            list.Add(gemstone);
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying TextFieldParser now... How do I get rid of Feild Name? I can't not seem to get rid of it from the results. I tried Dim i = 0 While Not My Reader.EndOfData if i=1 then "handle the row" else i=1 end if End While but still parsing the first row...

Comment: @shinya Can you post one line of example csv data you want to use?

Comment: I posted example csv data in the question section.

Comment: @shinya I added some code to give you an idea.  The Regex approach might win out because you have many fields that you do not use.  You'll need to test it out and see if it makes a performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I just found this whole TextFieldParser thing, and I do a LOT of text file parsing so I tested it....

On an 11mb file, with about 5200 rows and 300 columns.

It was 25% of the speed i was using when putting in a datatable.  It was about 15% of the speed when I removed the datatable code:

```
        Dim DataTable As New DataTable()
    Dim StartTime As Long = Now.Ticks
    Dim Reader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("file.txt")
    Reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    Reader.SetDelimiters(vbTab)
    Reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False
    Dim Header As Boolean = True
    While Not Reader.EndOfData
        Dim Fields() As String = Reader.ReadFields
        If Header Then
            For I As Integer = 1 To 320
                DataTable.Columns.Add("Col" & I)
            Next
            Header = False
        Else
            If Mid(Fields(0), 1, 1) <> "#" Then DataTable.Rows.Add(Fields)
        End If
    End While
    Debug.Print((Now.Ticks - StartTime) / 10000 & "ms")

    Dim DataTable2 As New DataTable()
    StartTime = Now.Ticks
    For I As Integer = 1 To 320
        DataTable2.Columns.Add("Col" & I)
    Next
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
        Dim NVP() As String = Split(line, vbTab)
        If Mid(line, 1, 1) <> "#" Then DataTable2.Rows.Add(NVP)
    Next
    Debug.Print((Now.Ticks - StartTime) / 10000 & "ms")
```

With the datable code removed:

```
        Dim StartTime As Long = Now.Ticks
    Dim Reader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("file.txt")
    Reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    Reader.SetDelimiters(vbTab)
    Reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False
    Dim Header As Boolean = True
    While Not Reader.EndOfData
        Dim Fields() As String = Reader.ReadFields
    End While
    Debug.Print((Now.Ticks - StartTime) / 10000 & "ms")

    StartTime = Now.Ticks
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
        Dim NVP() As String = Split(line, vbTab)
    Next
    Debug.Print((Now.Ticks - StartTime) / 10000 & "ms")
```

Kinda surprising to me, but I guess the datatable has more functionality. Another new thing I discover that I'll never use :(